# What is the best option for an AD only champion against a heavy armor champion with thornmail+frozen heart?

Tags: league-of-legends

I was wondering when playing with an AD only character like Tryndamere, what the best way is to deal with a character like Rammus or Malphite wearing Thornmail+Frozen Heart?

Answer (score 1):

first thing:
last whisper

if you dont play a ranged ad you might get a brutaliser into ghostblade, too for even more armor pen.

also: if you play ranked and you see they have a heavy anti-ad/full armor team comp, try to rush armor pen. runes (marks and maybe quints) so you can negate as much armor as possible

black cleaver is also a good armor shredding item

and the best tip, i can give to you: go as bruiser (for example tryndamere) on their damage dealer (ap carry, ad carry). theese champs have to buy heavy dmg-items and aren't so tanky in generell so you should be able to take them out quickly.

hope i could help

Thonar

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't focus him as long as possible.
2. If it's only heavy armor, get a Last Whisper.
3. Against Thornmail, either buy a Bloodthirster or Madred's Bloodrazor (since it deals magic damage, it's a good counter to Thornmail).
4. Thornmail does magic damage, so if you build a magic resist (MR) item (e.g. QSS (Quicksilver sash) against Rammus so you can cleanse his taunt or Banshee's Veil against Malphite) you will take less damage.

Answer (score 0):

Last whisper + Bloodthirster - armor penetration and lifesteal for enough sustain until you kill the enemy.

Answer (score 0):

You don't get any armor debuff items apart from Last Whisper. LW penetrates 40% of armor and therefore gains efficiency when enemy armor goes up - every other item removes or penetrates a fixed amount and becomes just less effective against tanks. 
Hit someone else and kill them last.

Answer (score 0):

For a champion like Tryndamere, you should be building damage and mobility w/ life steal and LW. You should also build a QSS to avoid cc. You shouldn't ever be attacking a champion like Rammus or Malphite in a team fight. Instead you should watch for the animation for Randuin's and try to stay out of range of the Frozen Heart while you try to kill the squishy champions. Its the RANGED AD's job to take those guys down.

For a ranged AD, building a Bloodthirster and a Last Whisper (on top of your IE/PD) will completely negate the thorns effect. Staying out of the AS debuffs from FH and Randuin's is also really key.